# Enable all disabled input and select element

Tags: jquery, html, performance

I want to Enable all disabled input and select elements before submiting the form so i can get all disabled elements values.

So i tried

```
function enable() {

        $('input[type="text"], input[type="checkbox"], select').prop("disabled", true).each(function () {

            if ($(this).is(':disabled')) {
                $(this).attr('disabled', false);
            }

        });
    }
```

This code is not working so could you please help me to this job.

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: `$('input[type="text"], input[type="checkbox"], select').removeProp('disabled')`

Comment: No it is not working.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try

```
function enable() {
    $('input:disabled, select:disabled').each(function () {
       $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
    });
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
function enable() {
    $('input[type="text"], input[type="checkbox"], select').each(function () {
       if ($(this).prop('disabled')) {
           $(this).prop('disabled',false);
       }
    });
}
```

Alternatively, you can enable all disabled elements without using `each()` like,

```
$('input[type="text"]:disabled, input[type="checkbox"]:disabled, select:disabled')
          .prop('disabled',false);
```

Or use [removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr) like,

```
$('input[type="text"]:disabled, input[type="checkbox"]:disabled, select:disabled')
          .removeAttr('disabled');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).removeAttr('disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use prop not attr,the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes.

```
 $(this).prop('disabled',false);
```